# Error deploying Django with ImageKit using Apache "cannot import name conf"

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, django-imagekit

I'm trying to deploy my Django site with Apache but I'm running into issues with the ImageKit library. Here's the error from /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "django.request"
[1.2.3.4] mod_wsgi (pid=17276): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfoliosite/wsgi.py'.
[1.2.3.4] Traceback (most recent call last):
[1.2.3.4]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
[1.2.3.4]     response = self.get_response(request)
[1.2.3.4]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_respo$
[1.2.3.4]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[1.2.3.4]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 264, in handle_un$
[1.2.3.4]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[1.2.3.4]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_mo$
[1.2.3.4]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[1.2.3.4]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[1.2.3.4]     __import__(name)
[1.2.3.4]   File "/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfoliosite/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
[1.2.3.4]     url(r'^', include('portfolio.urls')), # route root through portfolio routes
[1.2.3.4]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
[1.2.3.4]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[1.2.3.4]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[1.2.3.4]     __import__(name)
[1.2.3.4]   File "/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfolio/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
[1.2.3.4]     from . import views
[1.2.3.4]   File "/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfolio/views.py", line 9, in <module>
[1.2.3.4]     from .models import Project
[1.2.3.4]   File "/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfolio/models.py", line 2, in <module>
[1.2.3.4]     from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
[1.2.3.4]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/imagekit/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[1.2.3.4]     from . import conf
[1.2.3.4] ImportError: cannot import name conf
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this to happen? Doing "sudo python3 manage.py runserver" works fine, but Apache runs into this library error. Here's some more relevant info:

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite')
sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfoliosite')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'portfoliosite.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/bin/activate_this.py')
exec(open(activate_env).read(), dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf (the part I added):

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/portfoliositeenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/

Alias /media/ /var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfolio/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite/portfoliosite/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/portfoliosite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

This is really frustrating, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I was mixing Python versions, you can see some paths in the logs pointing at Python 2.7 while my virtualenv was using Python 3. I created a new virtual environment and changed all paths to use Python 2.7, and it seems to be working now.